# Find duplicate objects based on property in Java

Tags: java

This is my object structure.

```
List<Customer> customerSelection = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    Customer c1 = new Customer();
    Customer c2 = new Customer();

    c1.setName("Syed");
    c2.setName("Syed");
    Map<String,String> locationList1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Map<String,String> locationList2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    locationList1.put("DXB", "Dubai");
    locationList1.put("AUH", "Abudhabi");

    locationList2.put("DXB", "Dubai");
    locationList2.put("BAH", "Bahrain");

    c1.setLocationList(locationList1);
    c2.setLocationList(locationList2);

    customerSelection.add(c1);
    customerSelection.add(c2);
```

Here I want to validate if a customer is having preferred duplicate location, I should throw an error message. Any ideas on optimized solution?

Here Syed is having dubai as as location in location list which is invalid.

Comment: Why do you need a `Map` instead of a `List` for the locations?

Comment: @ayrton, this is an existing object structure, so I didn't bother about it which is having location id and location name.

Comment: I am not fully understand what you are asking. You don't want to duplicate key and value or you don't want to duplicate keys, or you don't want to duplicate values?

Comment: @SaidAlır, the customerSelection  list will have duplicate objects based on customer name. But customer should not give duplicate preferred locations.

Comment: You could make `customerSelection` a Set instead of a List. That automatically removes duplicates (at the expense of some extra processing, but you're going to have that anyway). However, I'd prefer to only have a set (or list) of the 3-letter codes. You can set the mapping between three-letter codes and full location names separately, and look them up as needed.

Comment: Why containsKey(Object key) method does not solve your problem.. If method returns true, thow an exception

Comment: S.LBarth, the point is customerSelection list will have duplicate objects based on customer name. But customer should not give duplicate preferred locations

Comment: @SaidAlır, please check my point. It can have duplicate objects based on customer name

Comment: Can you add this map as a attribute of customer, so you can check internally your list and prevent duplicate

Comment: I don't even see the duplicate location. `c1` has `DXB` and `AUH`, `c2` has `DXB` and `BAH`?

Comment: @SaidAlır, duplicate validation should happen only based on preferred location.

Comment: @weston, here c2 name is Syed. So both C1 and C2 are having same names, whicih is a valid scenario as per my requirement

Comment: So, requirement is, they can have different names and same location, or same name and different locations, but never same name and same location?

Comment: @weston, yes correct. Because the tester has given same name and same destination in two records, which is a invalid, which means the combination should not be same

Answer (score 1):

You can check the locations do not overlap at time of adding:

```
safeAdd(customerSelection, c2);
```

Using [`Collections.disjoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection)) which returns true iff the two specified collections have no elements in common.

```
private static void safeAdd(List<Customer> customerSelection, Customer newCustomer) {
    if (customerSelection
            .stream()
            // look at all the users with matching name
            .filter(customer -> customer.name.equals(newCustomer.name))
            // ensure all of them have no location overlap with the new customer
            .allMatch(customer -> Collections.disjoint(customer.locationList.keySet(), newCustomer.locationList.keySet()))) {
        customerSelection.add(newCustomer);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot add customer, customer with this name exists with this location");
    }
}
```

Or Java 7:

```
private static void safeAdd(List<Customer> customerSelection, Customer newCustomer) {
    for (Customer customer : customerSelection) {
        if (customer.name.equals(newCustomer.name) &&
                !Collections.disjoint(customer.locationList.keySet(), newCustomer.locationList.keySet())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot add customer, customer with this name exists with this location");
        }
    }
    customerSelection.add(newCustomer);
}
```

Comment: ::( I'm having JDK as 1.7, so I can't use 1.8.., If possible please let me know in 1.7

Comment: I'm sure you can work it out. Just use a for loop. Collections.disjoint is doing the hard work.

Comment: Thanks Weston. But how to call this method? while iteration of customerSelection? as I see you are passing safeAdd(customerSelection, c2); as hardcoded, because at the time of runtime, there can be multiple customers,right?

Comment: We'll you call safeadd rather than add. I don't really understand what you don't understand.

Comment: My point is why are we passing c2 in this method as hardcoded.. safeAdd(customerSelection, c2); we just have to iterate the list and validate it right? Please correct me if Im wrong

Comment: If you use `safeAdd(customerSelection, c2);`, rather than `customerSelection.add(c2);` you will never get an invalid list in the first place. Are you saying you _want_ an invalid list?

Comment: No weston. My point is you are passing c2 in method safeAdd(customerSelection, c2) explicitly. Because what will happen if there are multiple customers in the list? We cannot hard code all customer objects right?

Comment: At some point you .add the customers right? I'm suggesting safeadd instead.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look here too

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Customer> customerSelection = new NonDuplicateLocationsList();
        Customer c1 = new Customer();
        Customer c2 = new Customer();

        c1.setName("Syed");
        c2.setName("Syed");
        Map<String,String> locationList1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        Map<String,String> locationList2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        locationList1.put("DXB", "Dubai");
        locationList1.put("AUH", "Abudhabi");

        locationList2.put("DXB", "Dubai");
        locationList2.put("BAH", "Bahrain");

        c1.setLocations(locationList1);
        c2.setLocations(locationList2);

        customerSelection.add(c1);
        customerSelection.add(c2);
    }
}
class Customer {
    Map<String, String> locations;
    String name;

    public Map<String, String> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

    public void setLocations(Map<String, String> locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class NonDuplicateLocationsList extends ArrayList<Customer> {


    @Override
    public boolean add(final Customer customer) {


        for (Customer customer1 : this) {
            if (Maps.difference(customer1.getLocations(),customer.getLocations()).entriesInCommon().size() > 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Has Location duplicates");
            }

        }
        return super.add(customer);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I create a new class extended from Araylist, override add method and check all the stuff there, so that no one can add duplicate items there

Comment: The locationlist is a map object, but not list object. Please check it again.

Comment: But, please check it with a unit testing. Thanks Hakob

Comment: @Syed I've updated the answer, tested for two cases, it works

Answer (score 0):

```
You can iterate through list and check whether HashMap has same key present in other Customer's locationList.

for(int i=0; i<customerSelection.size()-1;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<customerSelection.size()-1;j++){
     if(j!=i){
   HashMap map   =    customerSelection.get(i).getLocationList();
   for(Map.Entry<> entry: map.entrySet()){
      if(customerSelection.get(j).getLocationList().containsKey(entry.getValue())) {
        THROW ERROR               
             }
      }

      }
   }

}
```

Comment: for(Map.Entry<> entry: map.entrySet()){ .. This has compilation problem

Comment: Use Map.Entry<String,String>